# How to decrease gap between items in griview

Tags: java, android, gridview, imageview

I want to decrease the gap between each items. I tried to decrease the horizontal and vertical spacing in layout but it's not working.

my code is: Gridview

```
<GridView
    android:id="@android:id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dip"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:dividerHeight="0.2dp"
    android:divider="#fff" />
```

gridview children code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="90dip"
    android:layout_height="90dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="90dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Output of this code

[image: Output of this code]

Answer (score 0):

```
android:columnWidth="90dip"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
```

These two lines are causing the gap. Gridview is trying to fit as many colums as possible with each colum 90 dp width in the total screen width. To decrease the gap , either change the column width or give a fixed number of columns.